# Day tickets for Sharm el Sheikh resorts

Tags: sharm-el-sheikh

We are traveling to Dahab, Egypt in February 2023 and flying in and out via Sharm el Sheikh.

Our flight leaves in the evening, so what we would like to do is leave Dahab in the morning and spend the day in Sharm, to eliminate any potential travel delays and have a bit of resort time before our return.

Do any of the resorts in Sharm el Sheikh offer a day ticket option, either all inclusive or otherwise? If so, can these be purchased in advance, or only at the time?

Thanks in advance